# Add item to the listview in a specific index

Tags: c#, listview

I want to add a listview item in the first row of a listview control, after sorting the listview items:

```
(sender as ListView).Sort();
foreach (ListViewItem lstvgeneral in lstvTotalGroups.Items)
{
      if (lstvgeneral.Tag != null)
      {
         if (lstvgeneral.Tag.ToString() == "General")
          {
             lstvTotalGroups.Items.Remove(lstvgeneral);
             lstvTotalGroups.Items.Insert(0, lstvgeneral);
           }
      }
}
```

However, the listview item is added in the row according to the sort instead of in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the listview, new items appear in sort order, not in the specified position.

> If the ListView.Sorting property is set to a value other than
>   SortOrder.None or if the ListViewItemSorter property is set, the list
>   is sorted automatically when items are added. Items are not sorted
>   automatically when the label text changes.

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)